# Rooted trees morphisms and categories

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

If I take the monoidal category freely generated by a single object $A$ and a morphism $f: A \otimes A \to A$, I end up with the monoidal category whose morphisms are forests of binary rooted trees.

Instead of forests of binary rooted trees, I'd like to obtain forests of rooted trees with any number of leaves. My question is therefore: is it mathematically correct to define the monoidal category freely generated by a single object $A$ and all morphisms $f_n: A^{\otimes n} \to A$ ? Has this construction ever been described somewhere ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment (if you can make it as an answer, I'll validate it). I've read about operads, but I'm quite confused by it. Some definitions involve category theory, some others don't. Also, it seems (correct me if I'm wrong) that in an operad, the morphism $f_2 \circ (f_2 \otimes id)$ would be the same as $f_3$, whereas I'd like to differentiate these two for what I've in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is fine; the details are exactly the same as in the binary case. You might want to poke around in the literature on [operads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory); the reason I said that is because any monoidal category generated by an object gives rise to an [endomorphism operad](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/endomorphism+operad). There's no issue distinguishing between $f_2 \circ (f_2 \otimes \text{id})$ and $f_3$.